# Vuetify: How to check if a row is expanded from slot?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to check if a `<v-data-table>` row is expanded from a slot ?

```
<v-data-table ...>
  <template v-slot:item.client="{ item, expand, isExpanded }">
    <b>
      {{ item.client }}
      {{ isExpanded ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
    </b>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution for this? I think I can figure out if a row is expanded, but how could you prevent the row from expanding if it's already expanded?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there are better ways, but the following worked for me:

```
<v-data-table
 <!--
  Declare an empty array that will be the expanded slots
 -->
 :expanded.sync="expanded"  
>
    <template v-slot:item.client="{ item }">
        <b v-if="expanded.find(x => x.id == item.id)"> 
            YES
        </b>
        <b v-else>
        NO
        </b>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```